# Append row to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How I can append array to my JSON after add row to database

```
[
  {id: 1, content: "aaaa", date: "2017-12-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 2, content: "bbbb", date: "2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 3, content: "cccc", date: "2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 4, content: "dddd", date: "2017-14-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 5, content: "eeee", date: "2017-14-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
]
```

and I add `quest` in my database with date `2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z` and how I have to show this i view, but I have to add this row to last value with date `2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Use plain JS `.push()` since it's simple array

Comment: If i use push it will show on the end of my list I have to show this beetwen end of this date and next date

Comment: `[...arr.slice(0, index), newItem, ...arr.slice(index)]`

Comment: But How I can know with index? If select date then add this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to keep the array sorted by date, you could use `push` and then `sort` the array by date like so:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 1, content: "aaaa", date: "2017-12-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 2, content: "bbbb", date: "2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 3, content: "cccc", date: "2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 4, content: "dddd", date: "2017-14-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
  {id: 5, content: "eeee", date: "2017-14-05T23:00:00.000Z"},
]

const rowToInsert = {id: 6, content: "ffff", date: "2017-13-05T23:00:00.000Z"}

array.push(rowToInsert)

array.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.date > b.date;
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: Close but dont sort corretly

Comment: what would be the expected result with given data then ?

Comment: They dont sort each items only 3

Comment: I don't understand. Could you tell me in what order should be the ids with my snippet ? (here, the result is `1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5`)

Comment: Ok sorry its work I have to Change something in my code

Comment: Oh, ok. Glad I could help then!